# Modeling segway robot in simscape multibody

Tags: matlab, simulink, robotics, simscape

Hello guys I am trying to model a self balancing segway robot in Simscape multibody, but there is a problem that I can't see the effect of gravity on my model as I run it. I have checked the direction of the gravity and the mass of my bodies but it still does not work. The inputs of the system are the revolute joints torques which are going to be connected to a controller.

[The simscape model](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m9P3L.png)

[The robot configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cKPK6.png)

Comment: What have you done to check the effect of gravity on your model? Furthermore, what are the values of the step functions in your model?

Comment: I am not 100% sure, since I do not know the contents of the 'wheels connecting rod' block, but I suspect the issue lies with the prismatic joint. This does not allow for rotation of the connector rod, so the pendulum cannot rotate. Is that indeed the case?